# Cannot modify LWUIT Symbol Table on BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry, lwuit

My view uses a `TextField` for a password entry. 
Password may have special characters, such as french accented characters.

I read that `setSymbolTable` method of `TextField` is used to specify all characters that have to be displayed when user clicks on the "symbol table key". But this only works on J2ME devices, when I click on the '*' key. 
Clicking on "SYM" key of BlackBerry devices allways shows the same symbols than before I added the call to `setSymbolTable`. My code modifications did not change the behaviour on Blackberry, but did change it on J2ME devices.

Do you know if this is a known LWUIT issue ? Is there another way to allow accented characters on Blackberry ?

Thank you

Yannik

Answer (score 0):

Blackberry uses only native input due to its complex keyboard semantics no other approach is practical. Customizations to the text field might be problematic in that case.

However, since the text field is native the same keystrokes required when inputing within other applications should work within a LWUIT application.

Comment: Native behavior work for a classic displayed TextField.
Unfortunately, this TextField has TextArea.PASSWORD constraint.

As a result, it's not possible to select accented characters as everything appears as '*'.

Comment: When I say native I mean we literally stick the TextField from RIM where our text field was and effectively lose control over it. Otherwise RIM input just doesn't work properly. As a workaround you can use TextArea and override key events, to intercept edit begin, when an edit begins just remove the password constraint and set it back again when editing is finished.